# Magento: Disecting the Default Theme

Tags: magento, themes

I'm looking for information about the default Magento theme including:

- Explanation of all directories.
- Explanation of files per directory.
- List & Definition of PHP snippets per
  file. For example, the PHP snippets
  used to place the buy button, review 
  starts, product images, etc

Does anybody know if/where I can find this?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just go look and see for yourself?

Comment: Yes Paul, you are right. I'm a bit lazy. But... I've been looking now for a week or so and can't find good info. I'm trying to avoid spending a ridiculous amount of time making my first Magento theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want doesn't exist.  There is no "skinning guide" for Magento.  The closest thing you'll find is the [Designer's Guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide).  If you're interested in learning how the layout engine works from a programming point of view I wrote an article [that covers that](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates), but you're not going to find a robust "here's how to skin Magento in thirty seven easy steps".

There's a steep learning curve with Magento, and no way NOT to spend a "ridiculous amount of time" on your first project.  Given how hard it is to find competent Magento developers, consider it an investment in the platform.

Comment: Thanks Allen! Before you even added this answer I read the article you mentioned and learned a ton. Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to read - and do not expect easy answers on here.  You are dealing with one of the most complicated Open Source Shopping Cart systems out there.  If you are having difficulties figuring out how to place the Buy Button, you are going to be crying by next week.

There is a lot involved when setting up a E-Commerce site.  In my case, a lot of swearing as well.  Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I believe you. I've been reading. What do you suggest I read? I'm having a tough time finding good stuff. I have building ecommerce sites for a long time now, just not in Magento and understand the frustration/swearing involved. Other ecommerce platforms are much less complicated, but DO provide a list of definitions (like the one I'm asking about).